# Forbidden access to S3 using paperclip and fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, paperclip, fog

When using fog via paperclip with the following configuration:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => {
    :provider => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :region => 'eu-central-1'
  },
  :fog_directory => ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']
}
```

Access to S3 fails with the following error:

```
Excon::Errors::Forbidden: Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
SignatureDoesNotMatch - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

Logging directly with the `awscli` tools using the same credentials and setting the same region works. I double checked the keys. Also, `aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket mybucket` returns `eu-central-1`.

### Update

I got it working with the `aws-sdk` gem instead of `fog`, which is what paperclip recommends in their readme. But I think fog should work too so I'm not marking this as resolved.

Comment: What are you using to store your environment variables?

Comment: I set them with `heroku config:add XXX=YYY`. When I check them with `heroku config` they look as expected.

Comment: So this error occurs in development or in production?

Comment: I configured only the production environment for S3. But if I do `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:reset` (which triggers db:seed thus trying to sync to S3) it fails with the same error.

Comment: Was this against the latest version of fog?